# VPN (client.ovpn file import to Network Manager ) not working but sudo openvpn command works

Tags: network-manager, vpn, openvpn

In Ubuntu 20 I downloaded the client.ovpn file from my company OpenVPN server and imported it into Network Manager and all worked fine.  I built a new Ubuntu 22 machine and now improting the the client.ovpn does not work.

I see these errors in the openvpnas.log on the server.

```
TLS Error: cannot locate HMAC in incoming packet from [AF_INET]99.8.222.97:50342'
Fatal TLS error (check_tls_errors_co), restarting'
SIGUSR1[soft,tls-error] received, client-instance restarting'
TLS Error: cannot locate HMAC in incoming packet from [AF_INET]99.8.222.97:44365 (via [AF_INET]10.1.4.225%eth0)'
TCP connection established with [AF_INET]192.241.220.18:42474'
Non-OpenVPN client protocol detected'
SIGTERM[soft,port-share-redirect] received, client-instance exiting'
```

If I run **openvpn --config client.ovpn** from the command line it also fails unless I use 'sudo'

How can I get the GUI Network Manager to work in Ubuntu 22 like it did in Ubuntu 20?

Comment: Ubuntu 20? and Ubuntu 22?  Do you mean Ubuntu Core 20 & Ubuntu Core 20 (*which is still in *beta*)? as the *year* format products (20 & 22) are different to the far more widely used *year.month* products on which they're based (ie. 20.04 & 22.04)   Most things are the same for 22.04 & 22, but many are different, but upgrades from 20 to 22 involve no user applications changing (*unlike 20.04 to 22.04 for example which is a different Ubuntu product*)

Comment: dan@HP-EliteBook-840-G5:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS 
Release: 22.04
Codename: jammy

Comment: Please correct your question then, Ubuntu 22.04 LTS is a different system to Ubuntu Core 22.  Ubuntu introduced the *year* products in 2016 (they are *snap* packages only, so no `apt install` works) with the different format highlighting the different products.  22 & 22.04 are different systems.  fyi:  22.04 is more power than a 22 system, however the *smaller* 22 also has some benefits such as faster boot, *release-upgrades* (20 to 22) do not change any user apps/packages etc... which differs greatly to 20,.04 to 22.04 upgrades...